# Identify and delete the first checked checkbox in a column [Google Sheets]

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

- Column C, from row 6 and onwards, is entirely filled with checkboxes.
- I want to delete all rows for which the box in column C of that row is checked.
- The name of this sheet is 'Today' and is in the variable of the same name below.

This is what I have so far, which does not successfully run and I cannot identify why:

```
    var values = Today.getRange('C6:C').getValues();
    var a = 0;
      while (a<=values.length){
        if ( values[a][0] == "True" ) {   
          Today.deleteRow(a+6);           //Here I add 6 to 'a' since the range 'values' started from row 6.
        }
      a++    //Increase 'a' by 1 and continue.
      }
```

Comment: _This is what I have so far, which does not successfully run and I cannot identify why:_  What is the value of `values`? Hint: Logger.log(values);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to delete the rows that the checkbox of column "C" is checked on the sheet name of "Today".
- The checkbox is put to "C6:C".
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

### Modification points:

- The loop cost can be reduced by retrieving the data range.
- When the row is deleted, when the reverse loop is used, the process can be simpler. Because when a row is deleted, the row number is changed. Please be careful this.

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, Spreadsheet service like `SpreadsheetApp` is used.

#### Modified script:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheetName = "Today"; // Please set the sheet name.

  var Today = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var values = Today.getRange('C6:C' + Today.getLastRow()).getValues();
  for (var i = values.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (values[i][0]) Today.deleteRow(i + 6);
  }
}
```

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, Sheets API is used. So [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services) When the number of delete rows is large, the process cost of this method is lower than that of the pattern 1.

#### Sample script:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheetName = "Today"; // Please set the sheet name.

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var sheetId = sheet.getSheetId();
  var values = sheet.getRange('C6:C' + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  var requests = values.reduce(function(ar, [e], i) {
    if (e) ar.push({deleteDimension:{range:{sheetId:sheetId,dimension:"ROWS",startIndex:(i + 5),endIndex:(i + 6)}}});
    return ar;
  }, []).reverse();
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({requests: requests}, ss.getId());
}
```

### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you. Pattern 1 shows me exactly what I was missing. I have a question though - If I try to use the same pattern to instead remove all unchecked boxes, it seems to fail. I have replaced the 'values[i][0]' in pattern 1 with 'values[i][0] == false'. Should this not work in the same way to instead remove all of the unchecked boxes?

Comment: @Nagaram92 Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about the detail situation from `it seems to fail`. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. If you want to delete the rows which have the unchecked checkboxes in the column "C" using the pattern 1, how about modifying `if (values[i][0]) Today.deleteRow(i + 6);` to `if (values[i][0] === false) Today.deleteRow(i + 6);`? But I cannot understand about your actual situation. So if this was not the direction you want, I apologize again.

Comment: Thank you very much Tanaike. You're comment was exactly what I needed. Thank you again.